# TypeError : Cannot read property 'create' of undefined. using sequelize for adding and entry registering a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting this error when I call this controller, Seems like they can't recognize .create method of the model,

How to import sequelize so that I can use it

```
const db = require("../Models/m_user");
const M_user = db.m_user;

exports.registerUser = (req, res) => {
if (!req.body.user_id) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
    return;
}

// Register a user
const user = {
    User_ID: req.body.user_id,
    User_Password: req.body.user_password
};

// Save User in the DB
M_user.create(user)
.then(data => {
    res.send(data);
})
.catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
        message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while injection"
    });
 });
};
```

Comment: The error tells you that `db` does not have a `m_user` property (it's `undefined`, so it can't have a `create` method). Check what the `../Models/m_user` file exports. Try `console.log(db);`, and if you can't figure it out, show us what that file looks like

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `m_user` is stored in the `db` variable - that what your import line suggests. So you are trying to access `m_user.m_user`?